# Mojave: How to grant apps permission in Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility on the command line

Tags: macos, mojave, preferences

I manage a number of macOS laptops.

Trying to automate a deploy of Mojave, I have found that some things aren't very automatable. One thing in particular stands out: the new permission scheme in Mojave for apps to access disk and other resources.

Since my environment is managed, users can't access System Prefs panels that require admin credentials.

However, the Security & Privacy is locked to admins.

I have a device management system in place that can run things with elevated credentials which is why I am looking for an alterative way to do this.

So: Is there any way to automate the addition of apps to this preference pane?

Comment: what device management system are you talking about

Comment: ManageEngine's Desktop Central; also, Centrify

Comment: Automate = Automator. Did you take look at it.

Answer (score 1):

[tccutil](https://github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil). But not the official one from Apple.

[brew](https://brew.sh/) has it.

Regards